# what does initialize mean in browser console..?

Tags: javascript, browser

im logging following in browser..

```
let photos = $('a').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href')
})
console.log(photos)
```

see this screenshot...

[image]

what does `initialize` mean in browser console..?? it should be an array.. why the browser doesnt see it as `Array`..?

Comment: it **is** an array, initialize[0] is a string

Comment: initialize has no special meaning in the console - that's just your photos *jquery* object - which isn't an array

Comment: `initialize` is the constructor of jQuery objects. Since `$.map` return a jQuery object, the console log it as of type `initialize`. If you use a minified version of jQuery, it'll probably be just `i`.

Comment: which browser are you using?